# How do I re-define a constant defined in a Rails configuration file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I define a constant in something like test.rb for a Rails environment, how can I redefine that constant for a test? Or to phrase it another way, what class would a constant defined in such a way belong to, such that functions like remove_const can be used on it?

It seems like it's attached to Rails::Application, but if I use remove_const on Rails::Application, I get an error about it being abstract and unable to be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a sneaky attack with `send`

```
Rails::Application.send(:remove_const, :Finisher)  # For example
```

I'm curious...what are you doing this for?!?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, returns a message saying the constant isn't defined. The use case is a constant defined in test.rb that basically says 'store things using methodology 1', but I want to write a test that uses methodology 2 so I can cover both ways.